# sqlite3_native.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm running into this sqlite3 issue and can't figure out why ; I browsed this forum for many hours and could not find a similar issue reported.
I'm using ruby 1.9.3, but the error message seems to invoke ruby 1.8.7 ; I even uninstalled ruby 1.8.7 then sqlite3 and then reinstalled it but that did not solve the issue

I'm running rails 3.2.8

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
```

and ruby 1.9.3

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
```

uninstalled ruby 1.8.7

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# rvm uninstall 1.8.7
/home3/user1/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p371 has already been removed.
/home3/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371 has already been removed.
```

uninstalled sqlite3

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# gem uninstall sqlit3
INFO:  gem "sqlit3" is not installed
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# gem uninstall sqlite3

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    sqlite3-1.3.6
i18n-0.6.1 depends on [sqlite3 (>= 0)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  Y
Successfully uninstalled sqlite3-1.3.6
```

reinstalled sqlite3

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# gem install sqlite3 
Fetching: sqlite3-1.3.6.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6...
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG.rdoc, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6...
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for CHANGELOG.rdoc, skipping
```

same error message again

```
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# rails generate scaffold project customer:string 
/home3/user1/ruby/gems/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02

Aborted
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]#
```

Anyone can please help?

Comment: Please show us the output of `which ruby`

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your prompt reply.
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]# which ruby
/home3/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
user1@company.com [~/rails_apps/myapp]#

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and I found this solution online that worked for me.

```
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

This will uninstall all gems, then install the bundler and then install all gems for your project.  Obviously you will need to run bundle install from a rails project.

Here is the blog where I found the solution http://www.zlu.me/blog/2012/10/16/segmentation-fault-with-rails-and-json/