# Ruby on Rails Console Seg Faults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been going through a Ruby on Rails tutorial and have been succeeding up until this point.  I simply try to run the rails console:

```
rails console
```

and I get this message:

```
/home/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so: [BUG]     Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
```

Obviously, I have tried other solutions on StackOverflow, including 
[sqlite3_native.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170156/sqlite3-native-so-bug-segmentation-fault) 
and [Rails s return: [BUG] Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569890/rails-s-return-bug-segmentation-fault)

and have tried the various solutions, such as completely reinstalling the bundles and gems, and removing and reinstalling different versions of sqlite3, none of which have had any effect.

I'm just looking for suggestions or things I'm missing as a newbie to both Ruby and Rails.

[Edit/Solution] Sometimes I worry about my own intelligence.  All of my problems were solved by using RVM to switch to 1.9.3-p448 and setting this is as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is it is trying to load a Ruby 1.9.3 version of the `nokogiri` library in a Ruby 1.8.7 environment.  This would most likely be compiled against all sorts of things that conflict with Ruby 1.8.7 (different versions of `libxml2`, etc).  If I were you, I would nuke 1.8.7 from your machine entirely, and focus on getting a totally sane RVM environment running 1.9.3, since it seems that is what you are actually trying to accomplish anyways.

This probably has to do with the `GEM_LOAD_PATH` conflicting between the 2 different versions of ruby.  Nuking one or the other is probably your best bet.

Comment: Look also at your `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` environment variables.